# Counting leading zeros in a vector

Tags: r

Let's say we have a few vectors containing some numeric data.
For example:

```r
vect1<- c(0, 0, 0, 60, 40, 80, 0)
vect2<- c(100, 0, 0, 80, 40)
vect3<- c(0,0,1,2,3)
```

I would like to count the number of "leading zeros" in this vector... so In this case I would like to have a value of 3 returned for vect1, a value of 0 returned for vect2, and a value of 2 returned for vect3. How would I go about implementing this in R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `which.min(!x)-1` or `sum(cumprod(!x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  One option is to get the cumulative sum where the vector is not 0, then, convert it to a logical and get the `sum`

```
f1 <- function(x) sum(cumsum(x != 0) == 0)
```

-testing

```
> f1(vect1)
[1] 3
> f1(vect2)
[1] 0
> f1(vect3)
[1] 2
```

---

Or may also use `rle`

```
f2 <- function(x) with(rle(x == 0), lengths[1][values[1]][1])
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something pretty simple I just couldn't think of how to do it. I'll accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple for loop with a counter here.

```
counter <- 0 
for (i in vect){
   if (i == 0){
      counter<-counter+1
   } else {
      break()
   }
print(counter)
```

You could easily wrap this in a function for reuse and just replace the print with return.